# Query to calculate sum of time with above 24 hours interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have time like 25:00:00, 10:00:00, 30:00:00 and I want to calculate the sum of the values from database. How can I do that the current query for calculating sum is

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss", Total_Time) + 
           DATEPART("mi", Total_Time) * 60 + 
           DATEPART("hh", Total_Time) * 3600)) / 3600), '00') AS varchar(max)) + ':' + CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss", Total_Time) + DATEPART("mi", Total_Time) * 60 + DATEPART("hh", Total_Time) * 3600)) % 3600 / 60), '00') as varchar(max)) + ':' +CAST(FORMAT((SUM((DATEPART("ss", Total_Time) + DATEPART("mi", Total_Time) * 60 + DATEPART("hh", Total_Time) * 3600)) % 3600 % 60), '00') as varchar(max)) as WorkingTimeSum 
FROM 
    tasker_usr.TaskTime
```

but I get an error

> Cannot convert from datetime to character string

Comment: What is your expected output? Please tag the DBMS that you are using. For e.g `Oracle`, `MSSQL` etc.,

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: You haven't updated your expected output. Is it `65:00:00`?

Comment: Yes it is 65:00:00 but how can i achieve that with Sql query

Comment: What datatype is `Total_time`?

Comment: nvarchar(250) is datatype

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you, then you should mark them as resolved(or upvote). Check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @fazalabbas

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fit your values into a `time` datatype. It stores only value less than `23:59:59.9999999`. Hence you cannot use `DATEPART` or `DATEDIFF` directly. One way is to split your values(*as seconds*) and do the sum. Something like

```
WITH CTE_SUM
AS (
    SELECT SUM(LEFT(column_name, 2) * 3600 
               + SUBSTRING(column_name, 4, 2) * 60 
               + SUBSTRING(column_name, 7, 2)) AS SUM_AS_SECONDS
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    )
SELECT CAST(SUM_AS_SECONDS / 3600 AS VARCHAR) + ':' 
       + CAST(SUM_AS_SECONDS % 3600 / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' 
       + CAST(((SUM_AS_SECONDS % 3600) % 60) AS VARCHAR) AS WorkingTimeSum
FROM CTE_SUM
```

*Please note that this will work upto `99:99:99`.If you have time values that are more than that, then you have to split based on `:` instead of hardcoding values in `LEFT/Substring`*

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this ?

```
Declare @Hours Table(Hrs VARCHAR(20))
Declare @Hour TINYINT, @Minute INT,@Second INT, @InSeconds BIGINT, @Cdate DATETIME

INSERT @Hours
SELECT '25:00:00' Union All
SELECT '10:00:00' Union All
SELECT '30:00:00'

select @Hour = sum(cast(Left(Hrs,CharIndex(':',Hrs,1)-1) as int)) from @Hours

select @Minute = sum(cast(Substring(Hrs,CharIndex(':',Hrs,1)+1,2)as int)) from @Hours

select @Second = sum(cast(Substring(Hrs,CharIndex(':',Hrs,1)+4,2)as int)) from @Hours

Set @InSeconds = @Second + (@Minute * 60) + (@Hour *60 *60)

Set @Cdate = dateadd(second,@InSeconds,0)

select datediff(day,'1900-01-01',@Cdate) [Day(s)],
Format(@Cdate,'hh') [Hour(s)],
Format(@Cdate,'mm') [Minute(s)],
Format(@Cdate,'ss') [Second(s)]
```

| Day(s) | Hour(s) | Minute(s) | Second(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 05 | 00 | 00 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your format is HH(n):MM:SS (that is, hours can have 1 or more digits), you can decompose the value and reconstruct it.  This requires string functions.  You can get the total seconds as:

```
select sum(left(total_time, charindex(':', total_time) - 1) * 60 * 60 +
           left(right(total_time, 5), 2) * 60 +
           right(total_time, 2)
          ) as total_secs
from tasker_usr.TaskTime;
```

Note:  This does implicit conversion from the string values to integers, but that should be okay if your values are consistent.

You can convert back to string:

```
select concat(format(total_secs / (60 * 60), '00:'), 
              format( (total_secs / 60) % 60, '00:'),
              format(total_secs % 60, '00')
             ) as time_format
from (select sum(left(total_time, charindex(':', total_time) - 1) * 60 * 60 +
                 left(right(total_time, 5), 2) * 60 +
                 right(total_time, 2)
                ) as total_secs
     from tasker_usr.TaskTime
    ) t
```